# Kendo grid dose not show any data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

my project is asp.net core 3.1 and i tried to binding kendo grid with read action. my kendo grid is empty and doesn't show any data

this is my action:

```
public JsonResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var data = _context.Products.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id);
            DataSourceResult result = data.ToDataSourceResult(request,
                model => new Product
                {
                    Id=model.Id,
                    Title=model.Title
                });
            //return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return Json(result);
        }
```

and this is my kendo grid:

```
@model IEnumerable<DomainModel.Product>
@addTagHelper *, Kendo.Mvc
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DomainModel.Product>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.Id);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Title);
        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 550px;" })
        .Scrollable()
        .Groupable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Products"))
            .PageSize(15)
        )
    )
```

thanks

Comment: Are you receiving any errors in your browsers console?

Comment: no i don't have any error

Comment: can you try this .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Products").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))

Comment: Could please also post your controller and route config? Just for good measure

Comment: thanks nonik and marco, The reason the read action did not run was because there was an extra link to jQuery on my view. and by removing it, the action is executed but the grid view is still empty and no data is displayed